# Vaadin: can not force to update the progressBar from thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I can not force to update the progressBar to be updated from the thread (FeederThread).

The button should be pressed, next the stream starts, the progressBar should appear.

I use Vaadin Flow and SpringBoot

My Ui with progressBar and button(startBtn):

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
@Push
@Route("push")
public class UploadEditor extends VerticalLayout {
private FeederThread feederThread;
private  ProgressBar bar;

private void progresBarChanche(boolean value) {
    bar.setVisible(value);
    bar.setIndeterminate(value);
}

@Override
protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {

}

public UploadEditor() {
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    VerticalLayout progresLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    bar = new ProgressBar();
    progresLayout.add(bar);
    bar.setVisible(false);

    HorizontalLayout layoutBtn = new HorizontalLayout();

    Button startBtn = new Button(" Start Thread", VaadinIcon.DATABASE.create());
    startBtn.setSizeFull();

    layoutBtn.add(startBtn);
    layoutBtn.setSizeFull();

    startBtn.addClickListener((event) -> {
       feederThread = new FeederThread(getUI().get(), this);
        feederThread.start();
    });

    add(progresLayout, layoutBtn);
    setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
}
```

}

And thread:

```
    private  class FeederThread extends Thread {
    private final UI ui;
    private final UploadEditor view;

    public FeederThread(UI ui, UploadEditor view) {
        this.ui = ui;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        try {

           ui.access(() -> {view.progresBarChanche(true); ui.push();});

            while (count < 10) {
                // Sleep to emulate background work
                Thread.sleep(500);
           count++

            }

            // Inform that we are done
             ui.access(() -> {
                 view.progresBarChanche(false);
            });
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

What wrong? 
PS I use Vaadin Flow and SpringBoot

Comment: Your example seems to work as expected for me as long as I fix some small compilation errors that seem to originate from incomplete copy pasting from your actual code. I only had to change the constructor parameter type from `AbstractUploadEditor` to `UploadEditor` and remove the `upload` parameter that was passed to `add`. When I click the button, a progress indicator appears. After a while, the indicator disappears just as expected.

Comment: I was sealed when transferred from IDE. Corrected/

Comment: maybe the problem is that I call UploadEditor by : Dialog dialog = new Dialog(); dialog.add(uploadEditor); dialog.open();  from main page ?

Comment: maybe  should turn on the push somewhere else?

Comment: If your actual `@Route` annotation also has a `layout` value, then the `@Push` annotation should be on the layout class. If the layout class has a `@ParentLayout` annotation, then the `@Push` annotation should be on the topmost layout that no longer has any `@ParentLayout`. You can verify whether push is enabled by adding a button with a click listener that logs the value of `getUI().get().getPushConfiguration().getPushMode()`.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand  I get DISABLED.     (import com.vaadin.annotations.Push;)

Comment: `com.vaadin.annotations.Push` is a really old location of that class. It was moved out from there in version 1.0.0.alpha15 (Dec 2017) and then ended up in its current location (`com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push`) in 1.0.0.alpha23 (March 2018). Please verify that you are using the right import and that you don't have any old versions lingering on your classpath.

Comment: Tried to use com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push (version com.vaadin:flow-server: 1.0.5) - not works.    Wrote in code:  getUI().get().getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC); - works.

Comment: Then I'm out of concrete ideas. There might be some weird interaction with either `@SpringComponent` or `@UIScope`. A breakpoint in `BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI` might give some clues to what's happening there. Still good that you found a workaround through imperatively enabling push as an alternative to letting the annotation take care of it.